# unix shell set command

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Want to know what set -A option does in the below command?

```
 XMLOUTFILE=${XMLOUTDIR}/${TEST_ID}
 set -A FILES "${XMLOUTFILE}"
```

Answer (score 3):

`set -A` is Korn Shell (ksh) specific (not available in Bash or POSIX SH) and it initializes an array with the specified value(s).

Here's an example:

```
$ set -A COLORS "red" "green" "blue"
$ print ${COLORS[0]}
red
$ print ${COLORS[1]}
green
$ print ${COLORS[2]}
blue
```

In your example, `${FILES[0]}` is set to `$XMLOUTFILE`.

Instead of using `set -A` you can also use for example `ARRAY[0]="value"` which is more portable.

Answer (score 1):

It sets an array value in the shell. This array is named `FILES`.

The `-A` will specifically delete the `XMLOUTFILE` entry, and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

set -A FILES "${XMLOUTFILE}" will replace the XMLOUTFILE entries from FILES array.